# PL/SQL "between x and y" does not work, if y < x. Why?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a PL/SQL code like:

```
case when column between 201203 and 201201
then other_column
end
```

I know that there are values in column that are 201203. So code should return some values. But it didn't until I corrected it like:

```
case when column between 201201 and 201203
then other_column
end
```

Why between keyword works like that? How it is implemented on Oracle Databases?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is ANSI SQL behavior.

```
 expr1 BETWEEN expr2 AND expr3
```

translates to

```
 expr2 <= expr1 AND expr1 <= expr3
```

Comment: On a sidenote.. I've tried to link the standard which was defined in ISO 13249-1. Unfortunately each, ANSI and ISO want money for the PDF, and I didn't find a public copy - wow.. imagine, RFC would take money, the internet would be a chaos without any standards http://www.iso.org/iso/home/store/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=38649 and http://webstore.ansi.org/FindStandards.aspx?SearchString=13249-1&SearchOption=0&PageNum=0&SearchTermsArray=null%7c13249-1%7cnull#.UNnboG_X5yJ

Comment: This is stated [in the Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/conditions011.htm) as well, which also explicitly says that 'If expr3 < expr2, then the interval is empty'.

Answer (score 1):

Consider

```
val1 between val2 and val3
```

as

```
(val1 >= val2) and (val1 <= val3)
```

Then what we have?

```
column between 201203 and 201201
```

is the equivalent to

```
( column >= 201203 ) and (column <= 201201)
```

If the `column` value is, let's say, 201202 then  the first condition
`( column >= 201203 )` will be false and the second one also will be false. That is why you are not getting any results. [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/conditions011.htm#CJAGAIDD).

Answer (score 1):

**In Between Clause, always lower value comes first instead of higher value.**

Ex:-  **BETWEEN 100 AND 200**

**instead of**

**BETWEEN 200 AND 100**

When Query Parser Parse **BETWEEN 100 AND 200** then it would be like this:-

**X >= 100 AND X <= 200**