# oracle : find dates between 2 dates with sysdate

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to get a list or rows where date is between dates based on current date;

i'm trying to get it like this

```
select * from myTable where calendar_date between trunc(sysdate) and trunc(sysdate-14)
```

and it returns nothing, while

```
select * from myTable where calendar_date = trunc(sysdate)
```

and

```
select * from myTable where calendar_date = trunc(sysdate-15)
```

would return rows with that days
what am I missing ?

Comment: [Related explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14032156/266304).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select * from myTable where calendar_date between trunc(sysdate) and trunc(sysdate-14)
```

change order in between.
first less date 
second greater date

```
select * from myTable where calendar_date between trunc(sysdate-14) and trunc(sysdate)
```

Comment: @Tejash u can't accept an answer withing fist 15 min or so

Comment: Ohh, ok.. got it. Sometimes it happens that OP just gets an answer and walk away. Hence, made the comment. Glad that you accepted it..

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select * from myTable where trunc(calendar_date) >= trunc(sysdate-14) and calendar_date <= trunc(sysdate).
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from myTable where trunc(calendar_date) between trunc(sysdate) and trunc(sysdate-14)
```

Comment: between needs the smaller value first. So it should be:  `between trunc(sysdate-14) and trunc(sysdate)`

Comment: Sure :) My mistake)